# MPI_Allgather generates Sigbus

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel

I'm new to fortran and MPI and currently processing a very large matrix row by row on different processors. I gather all the results on all the processors as it is needed. The following is the sample code which has the same structure as my real code.

I keep running into SIGBUS problems at MPI_Allgather, Line 49 of mod_test.f in the bounded function iter. How could I resolve this?

Compiler details:

```
$ mpifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 19.0.1.144 20181018
Copyright (C) 1985-2018 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

The code is compiled as follows:

```
mpifort mod_test.f main.f -o main -traceback -g -debug
```

**mod_test.f**

```
    module TEST

      include "mpif.h"

      type A
      real     ,allocatable:: pf(:,:)
      integer              :: nx=100, ny=10
      contains
      procedure            :: init
      procedure            :: iter
      end type A

      type(A)                 :: A_obj

      contains

      integer function init(this, x, y)
      implicit none
      class(A)       , intent(inout):: this
      integer           , intent(in):: x, y

      this% nx = x
      this% ny = y

      allocate( this% pf(x, y) )
      this% pf = 0.0
      init = 1
      return
      end function init

      integer function iter(this, y_iter)
      implicit none
      class(A)       , intent(inout):: this
      integer           , intent(in):: y_iter
      integer                       :: i
      real               ,target    :: a(this%nx+1), ar(this%nx+1)
      real , dimension(:), pointer  :: abuff, arbuff

      a  = 0.0
      ar = 0.0

      do i = 1, this% nx
         this%pf(i, y_iter) = i * y_iter
      enddo

      a(1:this%nx) = this% pf(:, y_iter)
      a(this%nx+1) = y_iter

      call MPI_Allgather(a, this%nx+1, MPI_REAL, ar,
     &     this%nx+1, MPI_REAL,
     &     MPI_COMM_WORLD)

      write(*,*) "Reached after MPI_Allgather"
      do i = 1, this%nx + 1
         write(*,*)ar(i)
      enddo

      this% pf(:, ar(this%nx+1)) = ar(1:this%nx)
      write(*,*) "Got the solution from another processor"

      iter = 1
      end function iter

      subroutine INIT_A

      integer             :: j, rank, ierr, size

!     - Allocate
      ierr= A_obj% init(100, 10)

!     - Iterate
      call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)

      do j = 1, A_obj % ny
         if ( rank == mod(j, size) ) then
            ierr = A_obj % iter( j )
         endif
      enddo

      end subroutine INIT_A

      end module TEST
```

**main.f**

```
  PROGRAM MAIN

  use TEST

  implicit none

  integer       :: ierr

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call INIT_A

  write(*,*) "Done with test"

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

  end PROGRAM MAIN
```

Comment: since you `MPI_Allgather()` `this%nx+1` `MPI_REAL`, the receive buffer size should be `(this%nx+1)*comm_size)`

Comment: Also you've forgotten the error flag on MPI_ALLGATHER - I STRONGLY suggest you Use the module rather than the include file, you are more likely to get an interface in scope that way and so have the compiler detect such errors

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, the suggestion resolved the issue.

Comment: an even better suggestion is to `use mpi_f08`. Fortran 2008 bindings are less error prone (adhoc types for MPI_Datatype, MPI_Comm, ...) and fwiw, the error flag is optional.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear - the error flag is only optional with the f08 bindings, otherwise you need it.